# XAMLServices.Load into interface

Tags: c#, xaml

I am using C# 7, .Net 4.7.2 and WPF 4.5.2

I want to use the XamlServices.Load method to import data from a txt file.

The content of the file looks like this:

```
<IMyInterface xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns="http://schemas.Demo" 
        x:FactoryMethod="Create" 
        MyProperty="MyValue" />
```

and the line in code looks like this:

```
IMyInterface myClass = XamlServices.Load("C:\MyFile.txt") as IMyInterface;
```

Because IMyInterface is an interface, *Load* is not able to create an instance of `IMyInterface` out of the box.

But the `x:FactoryMethod` approach doesn't work either.

The outer exception says

*An exception was thrown by calling the MyNameSpace.MyClass.Create method that meets the specified binding constraints.*

The inner exception says

*The array can not be empty.
Parameter name: match*

The Create method looks like this

```
internal class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
  // ...

  public IMyInterface Create ()
  {
    return new MyClass();
  }
}
```

What can I do?

Comment: You have to name the type in the FactoryMethod directive, e.g. `x:FactoryMethos="MyType.Create"`. How does your `Create` method look like?

Comment: @Klaus Gütter Unfortunately, no. MyType.Create doesn't change anything. The Create method is just a new-up, nothing spectacular. The thing is, I can't access the class directly, but by the interface only.

Comment: But the error message is different, now, or? For a [mcve], please add at least a skeleton of your Create method.

Comment: @Klaus Gütter Please have a look at the original post. I added the code sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Factory method must be **static** and reside in a **public** class.

The following works for me:

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.Demo", "MyNameSpace")]

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public interface IMyInterface
    {
        string MyProperty { get; set; }
    }

    internal class MyClass : IMyInterface
    {
        public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public static class MyClassFactory
    {
        public static IMyInterface Create()
        {
            return new MyClass();
        }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public static void Test()
        {
            var myInterface = XamlServices.Parse(@"<IMyInterface xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"" xmlns=""http://schemas.Demo"" 
    x:FactoryMethod=""MyClassFactory.Create"" 
    MyProperty=""MyValue""/>") as IMyInterface;
            Debug.Assert(myInterface != null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser and the example. Unfortunately, I can't use it because the class isn't public and I am in no position to change that. The protection level of the class is **internal** by design, not my design, to be exact. But I have to live with it.

Comment: MyClass may be private or internal - only the factory class must be public

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I didn't see *MyClassFactory*. This approach works absolutely fine. Thank you so much!